# Removing specific html tag

Tags: html, regex, perl, replace

I would like to remove a specific set of html tags, here is what I have tried

```
$str_rep="<table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr>";

local $^I = ""; # Enable in-place editing.
push(@files,"$report_file");
local @ARGV = @files; # Set files to operate on.
while (<>) {
    s/(.*)$str_rep(.*)$/$1$2/g; 
    print;
}
```

Html file has got only two lines - one is the page header and the 2nd line has got the full content including a couple of tables. Now I am trying to remove some unwanted table closing tabs which help me to merge tables together. Unfortunately it is removing everything after the replacement string. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: To make it clearer what you're trying to acheive, perhaps you could add an example of what your input might look like and what your output should look like.

Comment: @Simon here is the link to the html page http://codepad.org/Wu0ItDHI 
and here is what I am expecting http://codepad.org/jpcYbGHz

Comment: I am not sure, but if you want to delete some tags in html, you could use html-parsers

Answer (score 0):

You should escape slashes `/`, and simply replace the matched string by an empty string :

```
$str_rep="<table><\/td><\/tr><\/table><\/td><\/tr><\/table><\/td><\/tr>";

local $^I = ""; # Enable in-place editing.
push(@files,"$report_file");
local @ARGV = @files; # Set files to operate on.
while (<>) {
    s/$str_rep//g; 
    print;
}
```

Comment: This didnt help, whatever was there after the str_rep is getting replaced

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
my $report_file = 'input.html';
# see at this  v - you forget about one \/ near table :)
my $str_rep="<\/table><\/td><\/tr><\/table><\/td><\/tr><\/table><\/td><\/tr>";

local $^I = ""; # Enable in-place editing.
push(@files,"$report_file");
local @ARGV = @files; # Set files to operate on.
while (<>) {
    s/$str_rep//g;
    print;
}
```

I use diff for input.html and target.html

Everything works fine!